# Wireframe on a pointlight using shaders?

Tags: c++, opengl

I've implemented point lights in OpenGL 4.3 but the problem I have is that its very difficult to determine the actual radius of the point light. I image drawing some kind of horizontal + vertical line across a sphere that is the point light radius would be a good debugging tool, but I have no idea where to start - all I have managed is to draw a solid sphere centered on the point light, but as to how to get the wireframe I have no idea.

Any pointers?

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions:

You can use [glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE );](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glPolygonMode.xhtml) to draw your sphere in wireframe mode. But this will give you a sphere consisting of triangles.

The other way is to create a line-mesh that consists of the edges that you want to see for your debug-sphere.